# Update all rows with different values

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an Access database table liked to vb.net application.
And I need to update all rows with different value for each row!
**Table Before Update:**

```
 Column1 | Column2 | Column3  
   abc1  |   123   |
   abc2  |   345   

**Table After Update:**  
Column1 | Column2 | Column3   
 abc1   |   123   | x  
 abc2   |   345   | y
```

I'm using this code:

```
For i = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim expDate As Date = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
        dgv.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Today.Date, expDate)
        Dim conn1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constroledb)
        Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand
        conn1.Open()
        cmd1.Connection = conn1
        cmd1.CommandText = "update tblvac set fld1 = '" & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value & "'  where vid = '" & dgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "' "
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd1.Dispose()
        conn1.Close()
Next
```

Can anyone help how to do that?

Comment: Is your dgv bound?  There is no need to create a new connection in the loop - the same one will work for each row, you should also be using SQL parameters if you update/insert manually.

Comment: yes it's bounded, can you explain more please?

Comment: If it is bound, any new values entered into the DGV should be pushed to the underlying datatable automatically.  You should then act on the datatable rows not fish data out of the DGV row by row.

Comment: still no data updated!!

Comment: all rows updated with the same value (value of last row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Plutonix, the connection you can keep open and not have in your loop. I believe you may be having issues in the where clause of the sql insert on the ID not properly updating. try this:

```
Using conn1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constroledb)
        conn1.Open()
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim expDate As Date = dgv.Rows(i)(6)
            dgv.Rows(i)(8) = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Today.Date, expDate)
            Dim cmd1 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd1.Connection = conn1
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd1.CommandText = "UPDATE tblvac SET fld1 = @fld1 WHERE vid = @vid"
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fld1", dgv.Rows(i)(8))
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vid", dgv.Rows(i)(0))
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.Dispose()
        Next
    End Using
```

I moved the connection to a using so it will close when the loop is done and then parameterized the query so that it will allow instances of special characters in strings and not throw the sql off

Comment: thank you @Peter George, you just end 6 hours of work!